# Identifying IMAP mail folders (spam,sent...), folder names vary with servers

Tags: python, email, imap

I am trying to build a simple email client with python and IMAPClient. The problem is that the folder names aren't uniform for all servers.

If i mark an e-mail as spam, it has to be moved to the spam/junk folder from the inbox folder (?) .. but i am unable to do that because i don't know what the folder name would be (Spam or INBOX.junk or [Gmail]/Spam )

How do other email clients work with varying folder names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that for common EMail providers they have a mapping as to what that provider uses by default (gmail, hotmail, exchange etc.).

Another way of doing it is to let the user decide first time, persist the setting for that account and not ask again.

Mixed approach would be to try and detect all common variations and use the first valid one you encounter. If there are more then one simply allow user to choose.

Comment: Gmail uses localized folder names, so this approach will not work.

Comment: First approach : mapping is not provided for all the providers. Yahoo.com is one such example. Second approach: I really didn't understand. Third approach: I can have all the folders, "Draft", "Drafts", "INBOX.Drafts".....how really I determine which one is the real one???

Answer (score 0):

They try a lot of possibilities, let you choose one and/or create one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Roundcube have this in both the server and user configuration. I don't know about other mail clients, but I guess they either use heuretics, either by just looking at what folders there are or by using knowledge about the particular IMAP server.

Answer (score 0):

First there is **XLIST** command for Gmail (note that Gmail folder names are localized):
http://www.limilabs.com/blog/localized-gmail-imap-folders

Second there is a LIST extension called **SPECIAL-USE** that works in a similar way:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154